# php array of objects can't get object property (Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string)

Tags: php, object

been searching for a solution all day long...

my variable name is $categoryFetchedAsObj 
    var_dump results :

```
array(104) {
[0]=>
object(stdClass)#411 (1) {
["categoryHive"]=>
string(4) "asfa"
}

[1]=>
object(stdClass)#412 (1) {
["categoryHive"]=>
string(13) "ENERGY DRINKS"
}

[2]=>
object(stdClass)#413 (1) {
["categoryHive"]=>
string(7) "KETCHUP"
}

[3]=>
object(stdClass)#414 (1) {
["categoryHive"]=>
string(6) "STICKS"
}
```

and so on

i call a function...

```
createSelectBlock("category",$categoryFetchedAsObj,"onchange=\"this.form.submit()\"",null,'categoryHive');
```

here is the instance of the function

createSelectBlock($name,$fetchedNamesAsArrayOfObj,$selectEvent,$objPropertyNameForOptionsValue,$objPropertyNameForOptionsName)

and here is where the error raises

```
foreach ($fetchedNamesAsArrayOfObj as $rowArrayObj) {

                if(isset($objPropertyNameForOptionsValue) && isset($objPropertyNameForOptionsName)){
                $selectBlock.="<option value=\"$rowArrayObj->$objPropertyNameForOptionsValue\">$rowArrayObj->$objPropertyNameForOptionsName</option>";
                }
                if(!isset($objPropertyNameForOptionsValue) && isset($objPropertyNameForOptionsName)){
                $selectBlock.="<option value=\"$rowArrayObj->$objPropertyNameForOptionsName \">$rowArrayObj->$objPropertyNameForOptionsName</option>";
                }

        }
```

(Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string)

if i replace the 
    $rowArrayObj->$objPropertyNameForOptionsName
with

```
$rowArrayObj->categoryHive
```

everything works but the args of the function are not the same all the time ..  obviously

i search this site found some suggestions.. but nothing worked
here is what i tryied

```
$objPropertyNameForOptionsName='$objPropertyNameForOptionsName';
$rowArrayObj->{'$objPropertyNameForOptionsName'};
```

any ideas?

Comment: Im finding it hard to apply your specific situation but have you just tried: `$rowArrayObj->objPropertyNameForOptionsName;`?

Comment: as you can see im creating a select tag through php... if i replace $objPropertyNameForOptionsName with (categoryHive) everything works ,but $objPropertyNameForOptionsName value is categoryHive .. so i dont see why im getting this error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after testing and over testing .. finlay i got it working...
this was the correct answer for my situation

```
if(isset($objPropertyNameForOptionsValue) && isset($objPropertyNameForOptionsName)){
                     $selectBlock.="<option value=".$rowArrayObj->$objPropertyNameForOptionsValue.">".$rowArrayObj->$objPropertyNameForOptionsName."</option>";
}
if(!isset($objPropertyNameForOptionsValue) && isset($objPropertyNameForOptionsName)){
                $selectBlock.="<option value=".$rowArrayObj->$objPropertyNameForOptionsName.">".$rowArrayObj->$objPropertyNameForOptionsName."</option>";
}
```

hope it helped someone